# OnsenUi with Cordova load error

Tags: cordova, vue.js, onsen-ui

I just created template for OnsenUI with vue and cordova and executed couple of command thah should run it as android app, but I'm getting this error

[image]

Note I'm behind proxy.

```html
vue init OnsenUI/vue-cordova-webpack hello-world
npm install 
cordova platform add android
cordova emulate android
```

I found something about `LoadUrlTimeoutValue` in some config.xml, but not really sure where to place it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a filesystem URL has been used somewhere where a HTTP URL is expected. What happens if you search your code for "file:///"?

Comment: I think it is looking for base file to load to the web view, but maybe the app is not properly build or something. Running `npm run dev` worked pretty well in browser.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late to answer, still, I think it may help someone who is facing this same issue.

According to @Zveratko the steps followed was

- vue init OnsenUI/vue-cordova-webpack hello-world
- npm install
- cordova platform add android
- cordova emulate android

Some steps are missing in the process and that is the cause of the error. As this project is built with webpack, so it needs to be compiled before running it to android emulator.

Steps should be

- vue init OnsenUI/vue-cordova-webpack hello-world
- npm install
- npm run build
- cordova platform add android
- cordova emulate android